# Ecumenical Expanded

Tags: single-word-requests

I use the English word ecumenical correctly as it applies only to Christian churches.  Is there an English word that has the same meaning but would expand the idea of unity to all world religions?

Comment: The OED, whose main entry for *ecumenical*, gives a Christian definition, also recognises a general, and secular sense (2), with examples from 1607 ***2. gen. Belonging to the whole world; universal, general, world-wide.***
Abridged examples: *1607   Bp. J. King Serm. Nov. 13   This epidemical and œcumenical contagion.
1869   W. E. H. Lecky Hist. European Morals I. i. 160   No other literature exhibits so expansive and œcumenical a genius [as the French].
1882   W. H. Mallock Social Equal. viii. 213   Our œcumenical commerce.*  **Nonetheless @John Feltz is spot on**.

Comment: @WS2 you should post this as an answer so I can vote for it!

Comment: @WS2 Yes: you will, indeed notice its derivation from Greek oikoumene (οικουμένη), which referred to the inhabited world.

Comment: @Tuffy Yes, the OED etymology confirms that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [interfaith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interfaith) (MW)

> involving persons of different religious faiths

And see their example sentences, such as:

> Earlier in the day, Haley undertook an interfaith journey in New Delhi, visiting a Hindu temple, a Sikh shrine, a mosque and a church in old parts of the capital.

You can find many examples of organizations with the term "interfaith council" in their names, which are umbrella groups in a city or region of most or all organized religious groups.

Comment: _Interfaith_ only works in situations like monotheistic Christian or Muslim communities, where Faith (i.e, personal belief) is what's involved. Many if not most religious communities worldwide are not centered on beliefs, but rather on practices, customs, and common languages.

Comment: @JohnLawler citation?  See here: http://pluralism.org/encounter/todays-challenges/americas-growing-interfaith-infrastructure/

Comment: Note that this is local (southern white American Protestant) Christian usage.

Comment: -1 Not an *inter-* term. What we need is a *pan-* / *omni-* term instead, for **all**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**interfaith**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interfaith) or **ecumenical religions** (world wide religions).

***Online Oxford Dictionary*** has restricted the meaning of [**Ecumenical**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interfaith) to

> Representing a number of different Christian Churches.

Whereas,

***Merriam Webster*** has also included the liberal sense

> worldwide or general in extent, influence, or application

**Maxwell Nurnberg** and **Morris Rosenblum** represents Ecumenical as

> The root of this word is found also in economy which originally meant the management of the home or domestic economy, from the Greek word oikos, a dwelling or house. The ecumenical world is the inhabited world, wherever people have homes. Ecumenical, therefore, means world-wide and liberal as opposed to parochial in its sense of local and provincial, i.e. restricted to a parish.

So, you can use **Interfaith** or **ecumenical**.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you have two answers, please post them separately so the community can choose which one is better.

Comment: @RupertMorrish thank you for suggestion, but I suspect that is practiced here. I haven't seen two different answers by user on same question. If so, please let me know. Have I missed something?